# Suggestion on how to fix error "Could not find any information for class named viewcontroller"

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

When i try adding an iboutlet to my first view controller which is by default named viewcontroller i get the error message that says.... could not find any information for class named viewcontroller

**How do i go about fixing this**

i have also tried naming the view controller from the default class name to viewcontroller 1 but i still get the same error

in the debug area it also highlights that "Unknown class ViewController in Interface Builder file." and the same message when i change the class name to viewcontroller1

**Even before adding an IBOutlet to this very same viewcontroller, i can see this message down underneath in the debug area though it doesnt show up as an error or warning however it does cause me problems when i try adding an IBOutlet to this very same ViewController as then the error message appears and wont let me add one.**

Comment: Show the code for `ViewController` interface and implementation.

Comment: Check if ViewController.m is added to the target ("Target Membership" checkbox in the File Inspector).

Answer (score 0):

Also chceck this, maybe you mess around and changed + show the code for your viewcontroller class.

[image: Also check this]